# Google Map Maker API?

Tags: android, api, dictionary

me and few friends wanted to make an Android application which will allow user to easily add new streets to Google Maps. We explored the Google Maps API, but couldn't find anything like Google Map Maker API or something relevant... Does anyone have any idea is feature like this available, and where to look for it?

Thanks in advance,
Aleksandar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Google Map Maker API for you to use. The best you can do is add polygons to an instance of GoogleMap yourself. There would be no way to interact with Google's Map Maker service without Google releasing an library or extension to their Google Play Services on Android which I reckon would be unlikely to happen as I doubt there is a big use case for having Map Maker on phones.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker

And to Add marker

```
private GoogleMap mMap; mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap(); 
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Hello world"));
```

And read downward further, there is Customize a marker section that you need